# How should I remove the default home item & website name from the URL?

Tags: sitecore-client, link-manager

Recently I have upgraded our site from `v10.0.2` to `v10.0.3` using XM topology. After upgrade I have rebuilt the indexes / link databases as well.

But after upgrading sitecore is generating URL like below.

`https://{domain}/websitename/home/pathofitem` - from this pattern how I can remove `websitename/home` from the URL?

**SiteDefinition**

```
<site patch:before="*[@name='website']" name="websitename" enableTracking="true" hostName="localhost|*.xyz.com" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/websitename"
        startItem="/Home" database="web" domain="extranet" loginPage="/login" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="50MB" registryCacheSize="0"
        viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="25MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true"
        disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" />
```

Comment: Can you paste the code you use to generate links? Do you generate them in some background job or from a component rendered on a page?

Comment: Hi , We are not using any code to generate the links , but we use glassmapper to get the link like this Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Link.Url.

Comment: Are you using this link from another website within same Sitecore?

Comment: Nope , its a single site in sitecore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your hostname is not having your domain name.

Try adding the below patch config to your `app_config/include` folder and make sure this patch file is named such that it sits at the bottom.

Update the fields in upper case with Relevant information.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore>
        <!-- CUSTOM SITES -->
        <sites>
            <site name="YOURSITENAME" patch:before="site[@name='modules_website']"
                  hostName="YOURDOMAINNAME|localhost"
                  targetHostName="YOURDOMAINNAME"
                  scheme="https"
                  port="443"
                  virtualFolder="/"
                  physicalFolder="/"
                  rootPath="/sitecore/content/YOURSITENAME"
                  startItem="/Home" database="web"
                  dictionaryPath="/sitecore/content/Dictionary"
                  dictionaryAutoCreate="false"
                  domain="extranet"
                  allowDebug="true"
                  cacheHtml="true"
                  htmlCacheSize="100MB"
                  registryCacheSize="0"
                  viewStateCacheSize="0"
                  xslCacheSize="5MB"
                  filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB"
                  enablePreview="true"
                  enableWebEdit="true"
                  enableDebugger="false"
                  enableWorkflow="true"
                  disableBrowserCaching="false"
                  disableClientData="false"
                  disableXmlControls="true"
                  notFoundItem="/sitecore/content/home/system/Page not found"
                  itemwebapi.mode="Off"
                  itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly"
                  itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false"
                  robotsTxt="/robots.txt"/>

        </sites>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Hope This helps.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Gaurav in the comments, the links being generated seem to be consistent with links from a second Sitecore site (within the same instance).

You replied to say that you are just using a single Sitecore site. However, the patch file you have provided in the question specifies that your new site node **websitename**, should come ***before*** the default **website** node.

Therefore, what I suspect is happening is that you are somehow accessing the default "website" site.  At that location, links are being generated to the new site.

If you in fact only require the one main website. Then I suggest you update the config patch to replace the default. To do this change your config to something like this:

```
<site name="website" enableTracking="true" hostName="localhost|*.xyz.com" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/websitename"
        startItem="/Home" database="web" domain="extranet" loginPage="/login" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="50MB" registryCacheSize="0"
        viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="25MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true"
        disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" />
```